# How to name a file using do_upload() function

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, upload

I'm trying to upload pictures with personalized names. If somebody uploads a picture to some project, I want this personalized name: Project_imageX.jpg, where X is the number of the image. This number is controlled with a counter in my code, but it doesn't matter.

I read about the parameters that the function do_upload() supports, so, I tried to do something like this:

```
$this->upload->do_upload('form_name',$my_name);
```

the variable $my_name is filled with the structure specified before.
But it doesn't work.

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Thak you all!

Comment: `do_upload()` only takes one parameter.  You want to edit the `file_name` value in the `$config` array before you call `$this->upload->initialize`.  See: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: That is something I read too. So, I have to change the upload config everytime that someody uploads an image?

Comment: Or just simply rename it after it's uploaded.  `rename($data['full_path'], $data['file_path'].$new_name);`

Comment: if i rename it, will change the name of the FTP file? I'm totally newbie with uploading files in Codeigniter

Comment: What do you mean "the FTP file"?  CodeIgniter just wraps around PHP's native file upload functions (like `move_uploaded_file()`).  So, it just puts the file on your server.  If you rename it, it'll be renamed.  FTP is just another way to access the files.

Comment: I was talking about the native picture that I load to my FTP. "rename" option worked very well, thank you Rocket! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code Igniter's file upload class accepts the `file_name` parameter to specify the name of the file being uploaded (file_name - If set CodeIgniter will rename the uploaded file to this name. The extension provided in the file name must also be an allowed file type - re: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html):

```
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['file_name']    = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';

    $config['file_name']  = 'myfile.jpg'; // must include extension and extension must be available in allowed_types

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
```